# How to use group by to confirm a full bijective(one-to-one correspondence)

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble with two SQL queries.

4 tables: players, missions, completion-record, mission_assignment

many-to-many relationship between players and missions

player A is assigned 3 missions.

player B is assigned 2 missions.

player C is assigned 2 missions.

One query should return players who finish all assigned missions.

Another query should return players who didn't finish all assigned missions.

```
// query 1
select *
from players
join mission_assignment on players.id=mission_assignment.player_id
group by players.id
having count(mission_assignment.mission_id not in(mission_id list in completion_record))=0
// query 2
select *
from players
join mission_assignment on players.id=mission_assignment.player_id
group by players.id
having count(mission_assignment.mission_id not in(mission_id list in completion_record))>0
```

queries don't work since subquery in `not in` is dynamic.

Is it possible to pass player_id to the subquery?

**missions**

*id name*

1  1st

2  2nd

3  3rd

**players**

*id name*

1  A

2  B

3  C

**mission_assignment(associate table)**

*player_id mission_id*

1 1

1 2

1 3

2 2

2 3

3 1

3 3

**completion_record**

*player_id mission_id*

1 1

1 2

1 3

2 2

2 3

3 1

Comment: Have you tagged this with [tag:sqlalchemy] because you're using the Python library, or because you think this requires some "alchemy"? If the answer is the latter, consider removing the tag.

Comment: Both sql query or sqlalchemy work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

These hinge on you adding an identity column to MissionAssignments table (it essentially becomes a single Id for the combination of player_id/mission_id).  You could probably add one to Completion Record as well.  They will come in handy for future queries.

Try this for completed missions:

```
SELECT ma.Id, ma.player_id , ma.mission_id FROM MissionAssignment ma
INTO #CompletedMissions                  -- DROP TABLE #CompletedMissions
INNER JOIN CompletionRecord cr
  ON ma.player_id = cr.player_id AND ma.mission_id = cr.mission_id
```

You can select any or all from the temp table for display.  You could also join to players and missions to get names from ids.  Remove the "INTO" line to get query results instead of putting it into a temp table.

AND:

```
SELECT ma.Id, ma.player_id, p.name, m.name
FROM MissionAssignment ma
INNER JOIN Players p
  ON ma.player_id = p.Id
INNER JOIN Missions m
  ON ma.mission_id = m.Id
WHERE ma.Id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #CompletedMissions)
```

This will get you Assigned, but Not Completed missions with playername and mission name.

Also try this for Not Completed, but I'm not 100% on the results from this one:

```
SELECT p.name, m.name
FROM Players p
INNER JOIN MissionAssignment ma
  ON p.id = ma.player_id
INNER JOIN Mission m
  ON m.id = ma.mission_id
RIGHT JOIN CompletionRecord cr
  ON ma.player_id = cr.player_id AND cr.mission_id = ma.mission_id
```